# Change elements of activity_main by click from recyclerView in Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, android-activity, android-recyclerview

I need to change color of Button element from activity_main.xml by clicking the element in RecyclerView. The hex color value should be taken from selected item parameters.
Just because I'm new to Kotlin, do not understand how to perform it.

[image]

Here is MainActivity:

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        doAsync {
            val json  = URL("https://api.jsonbin.io/b/5e299cea5eae2c3a26db9cdf/2").readText()
            d("daniel", "json? $json")
//            val dataList: ArrayList<String> = ArrayList()
            uiThread {
                val stations = Gson().fromJson(json, Array<Stations>::class.java).toList()
                ElementsList.apply{
                    layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(this@MainActivity)
                    adapter = ElementsAdapter(stations)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Here is ElementsAdapter (recyclerView):

```
class ElementsAdapter(private val stations: List<Stations>) : RecyclerView.Adapter<ElementsAdapter.ViewHolder>() {

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): ViewHolder {
        val view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.context).inflate(R.layout.item_sample, parent, false)

        return ViewHolder(view)
    }

    override fun getItemCount() = stations.size

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: ViewHolder, position: Int) {
        val stationItem = stations[position]
        val highlightColor = stationItem.properties.color
        val colorFilter = Color.parseColor(highlightColor)
        holder.nameStation.text = stationItem.properties.color
        holder.lineColor.setColorFilter(colorFilter, PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_ATOP)
        holder.view.setOnClickListener{
            val curValue = holder.adapterPosition
            val selectedValue = stations[curValue].name

//              something should be done here to change button's color

        }
    }

    class ViewHolder(val view: View): RecyclerView.ViewHolder(view){
        val nameStation: TextView = itemView.name_station
        val lineColor: ImageView = itemView.line_color
    }

}
```

Comment: Can you add your activity code?

Comment: @Md.Asaduzzaman updated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Follow below steps to achieve this

**Step - 1:** Change your `ElementsAdapter`'s constructor to receive `Activity` instance like below:

```
class ElementsAdapter(private val context: Context, private val stations: List<Stations>) : RecyclerView.Adapter<ElementsAdapter.ViewHolder>() {

    ....

}
```

**Step - 2:** Create a callback function in `MainActivity` to change button's color

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    ....

    fun updateButtonColor(hexColor: String) {

        // update button's color here
    }
}
```

And pass the activity instance during creation of adapter

```
adapter = ElementsAdapter(this@MainActivity, stations)
```

**Step - 3:** Inside `onBindViewHolder`'s `OnClickListener` call the activity's `updateButtonColor` with appropriate **HEX_COLOR**

```
holder.view.setOnClickListener{
    val curValue = holder.adapterPosition
    val selectedValue = stations[curValue].name

    //something should be done here to change button's color

    (context as MainActivity).updateButtonColor(HEX_COLOR)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can change the background of a button using the `.setBackgroundColor()` method. In your case you need something like this:

```
yourSelectedButton.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor(selectedValue));
```

Comment: the problem is that the button is located in `activity_main.xml` while I make a selection in recyclerView that uses `item_sample.xml`

Comment: Just parse an instance of that button to the Adapter class